# How can plt show a single video file to html?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning

I am trying to use [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/AliaksandrSiarohin/first-order-model/blob/master/demo.ipynb#scrollTo=Oxi6-riLOgnm) google colab deep fake tutorial but I fail to show only one image in html format. This code snippet shows two media side by side one a photo and the other is driving video i want to see only driving video

```
import imageio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from skimage.transform import resize
from IPython.display import HTML
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

source_image = imageio.imread('/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/stat.png')
driving_video = imageio.mimread('/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/obama.mp4')


#Resize image and video to 256x256

source_image = resize(source_image, (256, 256))[..., :3]
driving_video = [resize(frame, (256, 256))[..., :3] for frame in driving_video]

def display(source, driving, generated=None):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8 + 4 * (generated is not None), 6))

    ims = []
    for i in range(len(driving)):
        cols = [source]
        cols.append(driving[i])
        if generated is not None:
            cols.append(generated[i])
        im = plt.imshow(np.concatenate(cols, axis=1), animated=True)
        plt.axis('off')
        ims.append([im])

    ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, repeat_delay=1000)
    plt.close()
    return ani

HTML(display(source_image, driving_video).to_html5_video())
```

if possible I can gladly accept help for the other thing I've tried for hours and failed:

- I want to put 25 images in a folder and *deepfake* all of them with same driving video then display them in a 5x5 grid in one video.

Comment: if you don't want image then remove `source_image` from `display(source_image, driving_video)` and don't use `source` inside function `display()` - use `cols = []` instead of `cols = [source]`

Comment: How about 5x5 videos?

Comment: to create row with 5 videos you would have to create list `cols` with 5 items - and `np.concatenate(cols, axis=1)` will create one row. To have 5 rows you would have to use it 5 times and later probably `np.concatenate(rows, axis=0)` with `axis=0` to join rows. And for every video you would nees separated `driving_video`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display single video you have to remove image from list - `cols = []` instead of `cols = [source]`

---

I can't test it but it works like this

- create list 5x5 with video filenames
- read every video and convert to list of frames
- use index to concatenate frames in rows and to concatenate rows to single image.

This way it creates list of images which it displays as animation.

```
all_filenames = [
    # row 1
    [
        '/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/video1.mp4',
        '/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/video2.mp4',
        '/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/video3.mp4',
        '/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/video4.mp4',
        '/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/video5.mp4',
    ],
    # row 2
    [
        '/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/other1.mp4',
        '/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/other2.mp4',
        '/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/other3.mp4',
        '/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/other4.mp4',
        '/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/other5.mp4',
    ],
    # row 3
    # etc.
]

# --- load all videos and convert every video to list of frames ---

all_videos = []

for row in all_filenames:
    row_videos = []
    for filename in row:
        # read video
        video = imageio.mimread(filename)
        # convert to list of frames
        frames = [resize(frame, (256, 256))[..., :3] for frame in video]
        # keep it in row
        row_videos.append(frames)
    # keep row in `all_videos`
    all_videos.append(row_videos)
    
# --- concatenate list 5x5 to images ---

def display(all_videos):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4*5, 4*5))

    all_images = []
    
    for i in range(len(all_videos[0][0])):  # use len of first video in first row  but it would rather use `min()` for all videos
        col_images = [] 
        for row in all_videos:
            row_images = []
            for video in row:
                row_images.append(video[i])
            # concatenate every row
            row_img = np.concatenate(row_images, axis=1)
            col_images.append(row_img)
        # concatenate rows to single images
        col_img = np.concatenate(col_images, axis=0)
        img = plt.imshow(col_img, animated=True)
        plt.axis('off')
        all_images.append([img])

    ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, all_images, interval=50, repeat_delay=1000)
    plt.close()
    return ani

HTML(display(all_videos).to_html5_video())
```